# What happens to report data after an SSRS subscription fails to send?

Tags: reporting-services

If a subscription fails to send due to mail server issues, what happens to the report data that ran? Does it remain in the Report Server DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on if and how you have caching set up.  With default settings, the data no longer exists on the report server.

Can you not just re-run the reports?

Comment: Where do you configure the caching?

Comment: If you're using the Report Manager portal, simply go into the properties page for your reports and/or shared datasets.  There are a few tabs that will contain caching-related settings.  If I had to guess, I'd say "snapshots" will be more what you're looking for to persist copies of reports on the server, versus just caching datasets.